# How do you run Lua code in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, lua

I want to run Lua code in Visual Studio 2022, but I don't know if I have to install something  and what I have to install. Is there an extension, or do I need
to install Lua from the official website?
I tried to run Lua with the [Code Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.CodeRunner), but it didn't work and said that I need to select a valid startup item.

Comment: I got it running back in 2021 on VSCode, and it was difficult. Lua is basically C. I am not completely sure of the relation, someone could offer more insight, but I do know that running Lua is equivalent to running C, you need a compiler to compile the code. Check the download site out and read some of the info. If you cannot get it running on your machine without VSCode then you won't be able to run it with VSCode! https://www.lua.org/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Visual Studio only has the ability to support the languages that it has to offer in the setup. I know for a fact that visual studio code has the ability to run almost all languages. Don't take my word for, I'm only saying this through my experience